# decompile framework-res.apk multiple resources exception

Tags: android, decompiling

I'm trying to decompile some apk using apktools, but on the first step when I'm doing:

```
apktool if framework-res.apk
```

I'm getting the following log:

```
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Multiple resources:
spec=0x01080293 drawable/ic_ab_back_holo_dark, config=-xhdpi
    at brut.androlib.res.data.ResConfig.addResource(ResConfig.java:65)
    at brut.androlib.res.data.ResConfig.addResource(ResConfig.java:58)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readEntry(ARSCDecoder.java:196)

    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readConfig(ARSCDecoder.java:165
)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readType(ARSCDecoder.java:130)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readPackage(ARSCDecoder.java:10
5)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readTable(ARSCDecoder.java:82)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.decode(ARSCDecoder.java:48)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.decode(ARSCDecoder.java:39)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.installFramework(AndrolibResource
s.java:384)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.installFramework(Androlib.java:365)
    at brut.apktool.Main.cmdInstallFramework(Main.java:193)
    at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:69)
```

My guess is that this apk contains lib that possess resource with the same name as the main apk's project. The question is whether I can fight and get it to work or leave it.

PS - I still can decompile the .class file using JV-GUI but I need the xmls.
Thanks

Comment: Ask the developer for the original code and work with that, or download it if it's open source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version of Apktools  is too low. you need download apktools 1.52.